# Unity Prefab Not Updating On Old Android Tablet

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab Active 1, on the latest version of android it can handle, and just recently, after adding accessibility features that shouldn’t affect anything, the balls in my game stopped updating. I instantiate a ball, and change a few properties on it, and then for some reason I think it’s not calling the update method. There are no errors.

I’ve heard using PrefabUtility to instantiate might help, but I haven’t done that just yet. I will update if PrefabUtility works.

Any advice?

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using please? The code that instantiates the prefab and the code that controls the movement please. Oh and the inspector panel with the properties might help too. It is unlikely that accessibility options on your development machine would cause an internal part of the engine to stop working and calling Update. I would normally suggest going back to the previous configuration to check if it still has the issue but I honestly don't think at this point that this is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops, this was due to me being a bit stupid. The main reason it was happening was because of a parsing error in some of the accesibility settings, as they were not saved correctly due to weirdness I can't wrap my head around with files in Android. TLDR: file did not save correctly, and so did not load correctly, and so data messed up, and so it errored before it could do anything.